# hMailServer and reverse DNS

Tags: email-server, reverse-dns, email-bounces, hmailserver

I have an hMailServer installation on a Windows 2012 server VM and need to properly set up reverse DNS + the mail server in order to avoid getting e-mails bounced back from certain big providers, which started to check this recently.

My server provider allows to set one rDNS entry, however I'm hosting several domains. So, I wonder what to set there and how to configure hMailServer.

There is a Default domain setting in the Advanced settings, but the help says this is only used for user which log in without an explicit domain. So, how can I configure hMailServer to use always the domain I set for rDNS?

Comment: Does your mail server have one public IP address assigned to it, or many?

Comment: Only one public IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is here: https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=reference_protocolsmtp

Under SMTP Settings >> Hostname. Change the Hostname setting to be whatever the public IP address's rDNS is.

> It does not matter what host name you enter, as long as it resolves to
>   the IP address where hMailServer is running. You may have 15 different
>   host names which resolves to the IP address hMailServer is running on.
>   If this is the case, you can enter any of these 15 different host
>   names in the Host name field.

Comment: That was it, thanks. In my version of hMailServer it's titled "Local Hostname" however.